# Scriptural reference for offering sashtanga pranams infront of dhwaja-stambham

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, practice

Respected members,

In Vishnu temples in South India it is a practice for the men to offer sashtanga namaskarams before the kodimaram (dwaja-stambham) and then enter the garbha-griha. Could you please give any scriptural references for this practice?

Thank you
Regards